# $A\subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ with equality if and only $f$ is injective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I've got a little mistakes with that:

$A\subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ with equality if and only $f$ is injective.

For example, if we take $f(x)=x^2$ and $A=[-1,1]$, we have
$$f(A)=f([-1,1])=\{f(x)\mid x\in[-1,1]\}=[0,1]$$
and
$$f^{-1}(f(A))=f^{-1}([0,1])=\{x\mid f(x)\in[0,1]\}=[-1,1].$$

What's wrong here ?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347880/proving-a-set-is-a-subset and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261157/show-s-f-1fs-for-all-subsets-s-iff-f-is-injective - you can find overview of some other similar results [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages).

Comment: @idm Strange, if you interpret $f^{-1}$ as "pre-image" then the $\subset$ should be $\supset$.  The question makes slightly more sense if we interpret $f^{-1}(B)$ as "forward image of $B$ under some (prospective) inverse function $f^{-1}$".  In any case you need to provide more context to make the question clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct statement is with equality **for all $A$** if and only $f$ is injective.

In your example if you pick $A=[0,1]$ then $f^{-1} (f(A)) \neq A$.

If $f$ is not injective, equality still holds for some $A$'s, but not for all.

**Added** If you actually mean that your proof is a proof of the statement, then here is what it is wrong with it.

You proved that this statement is true for the **one function** you chose and the **one set** you chose. But this doesn't prove that the statement is true for **another** function and another set. You need to prove it for ALL functions, not just one you chose.

Comment: ok, but what's wrong in my proof ?

Comment: @idm Nothing is wrong. For some $A$'s you get $f^{-1}f(A)=A$, and you found one for which this happens...... Unless you think that your proof proves the statement, which is not true as a single example is not enough to prove a general statement....

Comment: ok, I see. Could you give me an example where we have not the equality ?

Comment: @idm I already gave one, read my answer ;)

Comment: I got it, tks :-)

Answer (score 5):

I think you got mixed up. The statement is

> $f\colon X → Y$ is injective if and only if for *every* subset $A ⊂ X$, $A = f^{-1}(f(A))$.

Not “for *some*  subset”. The condition is, of course, always true for $A = X$.

Comment: ok, but it doesn't tells me way my proof is wrong.

Comment: @idm What do you consider your proof? And of which statement exactly?

Comment: N.S. already answer, tks anyway :-)