# A doubt on the question $C = f^{-1}(f(C)) \iff f$ is injective and the similar surjective version

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse, inverse-function

[Prove that $C = f^{-1}(f(C)) \iff f$ is injective and $f(f^{-1}(D)) = D \iff f$ is surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608707/prove-that-c-f-1fc-iff-f-is-injective-and-ff-1d-d-iff-f)
I have a doubt in the question asked above.

In this statement,

$C = f^{-1}(f(C)) \iff f$ is injective

I can't get why the following is not true.

$f$ is injective is not a necessary condition as if we choose $C$ contains $a,b\in C$ , $a\neq b$ and $f(a) = f(b)$. Which means $f$ can have a many to one relation and holds the equality.

In the same manner I'm thinking about the second part of the original question.
Can anyone make it clear.

**Edit:** *A similar question published earlier*

[$A\subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ with equality if and only $f$ is injective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109649/a-subset-f-1fa-with-equality-if-and-only-f-is-injective?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Your question is not clear. You don't understand why $f^{-1}(f(C))=C$ implies $f$ injective ? By the way, your statement is not clear. $f$ is injective if  $C=f^{-1}(f(C))$ for all $C$ !

Comment: Note: "doubt" in Indian English = "question" in US or UK English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $C$ [respectively $D$] is (implicitly) bound by a *universal quantifier*, so that the condition needs to hold for *all* subsets $C$.

In the given circumstances $C=\{a\}$ would be a better choice to exhibit a counterexample. Can you see why?

Comment: Oh thank you. I just forgot that $C$ could be any subset of $A$ and I was trying to pick a  subset which particularly doesn't obey the condition.