# If $f(U)$ is open, then $U$ is open. Is this equivalent to continuity? Or at least implied by continuity?

Tags: general-topology, functions, elementary-set-theory, continuity

Suppose $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is a continuous map between topological spaces. By definition, this means that if $V$ is open (in $Y$), then $f^*(V)$ is open (in $X$), where $f^*$ denotes preimage.

> I wonder if the following condition is equivalent to continuity.

- *Property 1*. If $f(U)$ is open (in $Y$), then $U$ is open (in $X$).

Now suppose $f$ satisfies *property 1*.
I think the preimage of $f(U)$ is $U$, because $f(x)$ is in $f(U)$ iff $x$ is in $U$. So the preimage of the open set $f(U)$, being $U$, is indeed open, because $U$ is open by *property 1*; this is what you'd expect if $f$ is continuous. So continuity should at least imply *property 1*.

Comment: $f^{-1}(f(U))\neq U$ in general.

Comment: Let $f:\mathbb R\to \{0\}$ be the constant map. Then is $f^{-1}(f(\{1\}))=\{1\}$?

Comment: Preimage of $f(U)$ contains $U$, but is not necessarily equal to $U$ unless $f$ is injective.

Comment: To complement the above comments, I will add some posts taken from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages): 
[Proving that $C$ is a subset of $f^{-1}[f(C)]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/347880), [Is $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$ always true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/78110) or [Show $S = f^{-1}(f(S))$ for all subsets $S$ iff $f$ is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/261157).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ send negative numbers to 0 and nonnegative reals to 1.  The image of $f$ contains no open sets, so condition 1 is trivially true, but $f$ is not continuous, so the property does not imply continuity.

For a counterexample the other way, take for example the continuous map $x \to |x|$ on the real numbers.  Let $U$ be $(0,1/2) \cup (1/2,1) \cup \{-1/2\}$  So we have taken an open interval, and replaced a single point with another far away point with the same image.  Then $f(U)$ is the interval $(0,1)$ which is open, but $U$ is not open.

Comment: Before reading your A,  I was going to give $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ where $f(x)=x-1$  for $x<0$ and $f(0)=0$ and$ f(x)=x+1$ for $x>0$ but your example is simpler,