# What's wrong with my counter example on $f^{-1}(f(A))=A \iff f$ is injective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$f:X \to Y , A\subset X, B\subset Y$

$f^{-1}(f(A))=A \iff f$ is injective

My counter example is setting function $f$ and $A$ such that
$A=\{1, 2\}, f(A)=\{a\}, f^{-1}(f(\{a\}))=\{1, 2\}$ which is setting preimage of f(A) to A

for me it seems such definition of subset and function holds

$f^{-1}(f(A))=A $

because by definition of preimage $\{1, 2\}=\{x\in X \vert f(x)=A \}$

and also non injectivity.

but my text book and another lecture insist above property is true.

Can someone find error in my counter expamle please?

Comment: Perhaps this will be useful to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261157/show-s-f-1fs-for-all-subsets-s-iff-f-is-injective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false. What is true is $f$ is injective iff $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$ **for every** set $A$ in the domain of $f$.

Comment: OHHHHH MAA GAAA...
I'm baka desu... small brain..
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

$$f^{-1}(f(A))=A \implies f(x)$$ is a  bijection (one-one(injective) and onto): $f: A \rightarrow B$, where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$ and $Y$. Also the bijectivity of $f(x): A \rightarrow B$ is both  necessary and sufficient for  $f^{-1}(x)$ to exist.