# Prove that $f$ is injective given that $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a function. Prove that if for every $A\subseteq X$, we have $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$ then $f$ is one to one (injective)

**My try:** Let $x,x’\in X$ be such that $f(x)=f(x')$. We need to show that $x=x'$. So we have $$f^{-1}(f(x)) = f^{-1}(f(x'))$$According to the assumption we have $$x = x'$$I don't know whether my proof is correct and rigorous.

Comment: Another question about this problem: [Show $S = f^{-1}(f(S))$ for all subsets $S$ iff $f$ is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/261157)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be correct if $f$ had an inverse, but you are not assuming that.

You can say that, if $A=\{x\}$, then\begin{align}\{x\}&=A\\&=f^{-1}\bigl(f(A)\bigr)\\&=f^{-1}\bigl(\bigl\{f(x)\bigr\}\bigr)\\&\supset\{x,x'\}\end{align}and that therefore $x'=x$.

Comment: Thanks. Why my proof requires that $f^{-1}$ exists?

Comment: Because you wrote $f^{-1}\bigl(f(x)\bigr)$. This notation implies that $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$.

Comment: So my definition of $f^{-1}$ is different from yours? Also I couldn't understand how you got $f^{-1}\bigl(f(A)\bigr)=f^{-1}\bigl(\{x\}\bigr)\supset\{x,x'\}$.

Comment: It was a typo; I meant $f^{-1}\bigl(\bigl\{f(x)\bigr\}\bigr)$. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your answer but there are some confusions still. What's the difference between my definition of $f^{-1}$ and yours? Why we have $f^{-1}\bigl(\bigl\{f(x)\bigr\}\bigr)\supset\{x,x'\}$?

Comment: My definition of $f^{-1}(A)$, with $A\subset Y$, is $\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in A\}$. So, since $f(x)=f(x')$, both $x$ and $x'$ belong to $f^{-1}\bigl(\bigl\{f(x)\bigr\}\bigr)$, and therefore $\{x,x'\}\subset f^{-1}\bigl(\bigl\{f(x)\bigr\}\bigr)$. How do you define $f^{-1}$?

Comment: I see. So when we write $f^{-1}(a)$ where $a$ is an element not a set, we are assuming that inverse function exists, right?

Comment: Yes, although for some authors $f^{-1}(a)$ is a way of writing $f^{-1}\bigl(\{a\}\bigr)$.